# Use 2-measure difference score as primary predictor, or use single measure constructed to assess a difference?

Tags: survey, measure-theory

I'm looking for help on a research design question. A colleague and I are looking to examine perceived attractiveness of oneself relative to the "average person" as a predictor of an outcome phenomenon. We have a measure of attractiveness that asks individuals to rate the attractiveness of several features/qualities on a 0 ("Not attractive at all") to 8 ("Extremely attractive") scale. We are considering two options:

Option 1: Participants complete Attractiveness Rating Scale (0-8 scale) for their own features; Participants complete modified Attractiveness Rating Scale (0-8 scale) with respect to the "average person," and we use a difference score as our predictor of our outcome.

Option 2: Participants complete one modified Attractiveness Rating Scale that asks participants to rate their own attractiveness relative to the "average person" on a -4 ("much less attractive than the average person") to 4 ("much more attractive than the average person") scale.

We want to avoid biasing our results/compromising our findings; however, we are not sure which is the most statistically sound option. Does this forum recommend using a difference score from an original and slightly-modified measure version (Option 1), or creating a substantially modified measure that represents the myself-vs-other discrepancy in attractiveness perceptions directly?

Thanks in advance.